# Dear Dad and Mom / dear Dad and Mom / dear dad and mom

Tags: proper-nouns, capitalization, kinship-terms

My question is precise, yet, even after consulting the Internet and this forum, I didn't manage to find an answer to the question, which is the following: which of the following ways to write that sentence is correct in terms of capitalization? I personally think that the first is correct, but the second might be more correct, which I doubt a bit. So, please, help me figure it out.

1. I am really proud of you, Dear Dad and Mom.
2. I am really proud of you, dear Dad and Mom.
3. I am really proud of you, dear dad and mom.

P.S. I also tried to get some help from the Ngram Viewer, but I think that most of the instances of this phrase are found at the beginning, which is why the word *dear* is capitalized. In my example, as you see, that word is not at the beginning.

1. [Dear Dad and Mom,dear dad and mom,Dear dad and mom,dear Dad and Mom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dear+Dad+and+Mom%2Cdear+dad+and+mom%2CDear+dad+and+mom%2Cdear+Dad+and+Mom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
2. [dear Dad,dear dad,Dear Dad,Dear dad](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dear+Dad%2C+dear+dad%2C+Dear+Dad%2C+Dear+dad&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Usually Mom would come first.

Comment: Indeed. This is a [Siamese twin phrase](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_Siamese_twins) in my lexicon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is correct, as it's part of a sentence and not the salutation of a letter.

*Father, Dad, Papa, Mom, Mum* etc. are usually written with a capital letter when used  as a form of address.